# ActionBarSherlock with custom Drawable icon that has large intrinsic width / height - appears too large

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using a custom `Drawable` class to provide icons for my `ActionBarSherlock`. The custom `Drawable` class, `SVGDrawable`, is actually part of my own SVG library. I've developed this library for other areas of this application, but I'm finding it useful to create `ActionBar` icons in SVG format too, because it avoids having to generate multiple images to support various densities. So, for the purpose of this question, the SVG stuff isn't really relevant. All that is relevant is that `SVGDrawable` renders content based on the contents of an `.svg` file, and that the intrinsic width / height is considered to be the original `.svg` document's width and height.

It all works perfectly well, except for the one small issue in that the `SVGDrawable` is asked to `draw()` its image using the intrinsic width and height, rather than some width and height that fits within the `ActionBarSherlock`. The `SVGDrawable`'s `getIntrinsicHeight()` returns the original height of the SVG document (and the same goes for the width), and therefore if for instance the original SVD document is 300px square, then that's what the `SVGDrawable` will be rendered at.

I suppose that the `ActionBarSherlock` basically wants its icon `Drawables` to draw at their own intrinsic sizes, because in the usual case you would use image resource drawables, and those drawables would have already been authoried to be exactly the correct sizes for the various densities.

Initially, I wrongly assumed that the `SVGDrawable`s setBounds() would be called with some values that state how large the `ActionBarSherlock` permits the icon to be.

For my situation, the only work-around I can think of is to add a method like `setIntrinsicDimensions(int width, int height)` which would basically override the dimensions read from the original SVG document. I suppose that, when adding the `SVGDrawable` programmatically to the `ActionBarSherlock`, I would also call this method and supply a suitable width and height, where the height is the height of the `ActionBarSherlock` minus some padding.

Any better approach, anyone?